# How to use a user-defined variable in MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to use a CASE statement in MySQL based on a variable. I tried the code below; however, I have found that "The SELECT statement cannot refer to system variables or user-defined variables". What I am trying to achieve is that I have an input date. I get its day of week so I know which day it is on (1 is Sunday). I then only want rows returned in the query that have the day set to "Y" (e.g., if day of week is 1 then stt_sunday is "Y"). The table has:

```
stt_id
stt_start_date
stt_end_date
stt_start_time
stt_end_time
stt_sunday
stt_monday
stt_tuesday
stt_wednesday
stt_thursday
stt_friday
stt_saturday
```

My code is:

```
String selectQry1 = (" SET @clickedDateDOW = clickedDateDOW; " +
    " SELECT st_type, csm_session_timetable.stt_id, stt_start_date, stt_end_date, stt_start_time, stt_end_time " +
        " FROM csm_session_type, csm_session_timetable " + 
        " WHERE csm_session_type.cli_id = ? " +
            " AND csm_session_type.prm_id = ? " +
            " AND csm_session_type.st_id = csm_session_timetable.st_id " +
            " AND (csm_session_timetable.stt_end_date IS NULL || csm_session_timetable.stt_end_date > ?)  " +
            " AND csm_session_timetable.gym_id = ? " +
            " AND CASE " +
                " WHEN @clickedDateDOW = 1 AND stt_sunday LIKE 'Y' THEN 1 " +
                " WHEN @clickedDateDOW = 2 AND stt_monday LIKE 'Y' THEN 1 " +
            " WHEN @clickedDateDOW = 3 AND stt_tuesday LIKE 'Y' THEN 1 " +
            " WHEN @clickedDateDOW = 4 AND stt_wednesday LIKE 'Y' THEN 1 " +
            " WHEN @clickedDateDOW = 5 AND stt_thursday LIKE 'Y' THEN 1 " +
            " WHEN @clickedDateDOW = 6 AND stt_friday LIKE 'Y' THEN 1 " +
            " WHEN @clickedDateDOW = 7 AND stt_saturday LIKE 'Y' THEN 1 " +
        " ORDER BY stt_start_date DESC, stt_start_time, stt_end_date DESC;");
```

Comment: Most of it LOOKS ok, but you have C# logical or via || (double-pipe), but not a SQL "OR".,  But what are your "?" place-holder used for???  Are you intending it as a stored procedure and passing AS a parameter?

Comment: @DRapp Yes, this is a stored procedure (as per the title). I have not had any issues with using || in place of OR. However, if this is not standard I will change it to OR. Without the SET and CASE it works fine. However, I want to decrease the rows returned to only those rows that have a day set to 'Y' that is equivalent to the date's day.